# What is this and how can this happen? Is this a security issue or can it be a virus?

Tags: security, 15.04, memory-usage, malware, android-studio

From the last 3-4 days, my laptop has started becoming much laggy when I'm working on Android Studio or if it is just running in the background.

So, today again I was working in Android Studio. My laptop became much laggier and suddenly this happened.

Whenever I tried to write something in the editor window, the random text "Jrstlc" started appearing. Whenever I hit a button on my keyboard only this text was being repeatedly written in the editor.

This screenshot shows the "Jrstlc" being repeatedly written:

[image]

I thought of quitting Android Studio, but it again lagged there and didn't quit. But everything else started working at a normal speed.

I opened up the System Monitor and it showed Android Studio using '1.2gb' memory.

This screenshot shows the high memory usage by android-studio:

[image]

And then down the list I saw some services starting with the name 'tracker'.

This screenshot shows the 'tracker' services:

[image]

I'm more concerned about it now.

Why that keyboard issue happened and why android-studio is eating so much memory?

Is there any possibility of a virus?

Comment: Image uploading is currently unavailable due to ISP problems of SE: https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/599934236188090368, but it should come back soon... Then you can use the [edit] button under your question.

Comment: Thanks. I will add the screenshots when image uploading becomes available soon.

Comment: I've added the links to screenshots. I have 3 of them but can post only 2 because of the restrictions of the site.

And I can't even add the screenshots because I don't have the required 10 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Tracker is a search engine, search tool and metadata storage system.

   It allows you to find the proverbial needle in your computer's haystack as well as providing a one stop solution to the organisation, storage and categorisation of your data.
   <sub>[Source](http://ttps://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker) and [more Infos](https://askubuntu.com/q/346211/367165), thx @solsTiCe for the hint</sub>
2. `tracker` can consume a lot of resources

   Install `iotop`, a simple top-like I/O monitor

   ```
   sudo apt-get install iotop
   ```

   Start `iotop` in a terminal and monitor the output of `tracker` processes
3. The memory usage of development environments of this type is normal.

   Install `htop`, a interactive process viewer

   ```
   sudo apt-get install htop
   ```

   and start with `htop` in a terminal. Press <kbd>F5</kbd> for the tree view and search for `java`. Look at the information on the sub-processes. There you'll see more detail, who needs as much RAM.
4. `Jrstlc`, sorry, no idea.

   But a virus you can exclude my opinion.

Comment: Look at http://askubuntu.com/q/346211/350004 or http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2217610 for more info about *tracker* app

Comment: Thanks A.B. Can you please add the third screenshot too? 
I've updated the description with the link to screenshot.

Comment: Thanks @A.B. 
You have mentioned in your answer that `tracker` can consume a lot of resources.

But you can see in the screenshot, it is not consuming much memory.

And what is `iotop` used for?

Comment: For disk input output

Answer (score 0):

The tracker app sounds like a good idea, but it's not ready for prime time. I also use Android Studio and notice laggy performance. the "top" command shows the various tracker processes running at the top of the list. I see my load average reaching 6 or 7 and my memory use nearing 100%. This is with the default settings for tracker after exiting Android Studio. It is supposed to do its work without interfering with normal use, but that is not the case. I see other software failing (i.e., network apps timing out) due to the excessive load. You can adjust tracker settings (in 15.04) by running "tracker-preferences". I have removed everything from the "locations" list, now my system is usable again.