# Problem with "tracker-miner-fs" (Ubuntu 20.10)

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

tracker-miner-fs takes a heavy CPU load. I understand what it does, and I want to keep it there. I wanted to know if there is a way to make the process shorter by running the process on
8 CPU cores instead of 1.
Or does disabling it has significant performance degradation?

Comment: Some patience. Once the files are indexed, the CPU load will decrease. If you want to use it, you need to cope with this issue. I dont' think you control what CPU it uses - this is determined by how the application is programmed. Disabling will improve performance rather than decrease it, but will disable full text file search.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: renice can tone down a process.   renice -n 12 <pidof tracker-fs>  or to really hammer it ....  while true; do for i in $(echo $(pidof tracker-miner-fs)); do echo  "$i"; renice -n 20 "$i"; done; sleep 5 ; done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is normal that `tracker-miner-fs` takes up CPU power while it is performing the indexing. However, it should stop whenever the indexing is finished, and subsequently kick in when there are new or changed files. It is also quite normal that it takes up CPU power for a few minutes after logging in.

So you need to be patient: the CPU load will decrease.

You cannot change what CPU it uses. This is determined by how the application is programmed. That it uses only a single CPU may be rather favorably. If you have multiple cores (most modern systems do), these are left available and as a result, the system continues to feel responsive while `tracker-miner-fs` is doing its work.

[Disabling tracker](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187191/tracker-process-taking-lot-of-cpu/1187273#1187273) will improve performance rather than decrease it, but will disable full text file search