# Ubuntu 20.4 .cache tracker is taking my space

Tags: 20.04, disk-usage, workspaces, tracker, user-space

I have 200 gb of space in my portion and the .cache tracker meta.db-wal took 140gb of that space and I don’t know how to clear it. I saw that you can disable the tracker but without actually informing me how to clear or clean it to get the space back. someone also suggested deleting the tracker file but because I had Ubuntu issues before and I am afraid of deleting files that I might need in the future.

Comment: Very exceptional and not normal that your cache tracker would require 140 GB. I surely would reset tracker and let it reindex, or perhaps try to VACUUM the database with `sqlite3`.

Comment: Yes that is my issue. But that is the volume that was taken by meta.db-wal. I do simulations on my pc and I can do them anymore because of this issue.

Comment: @vanadium how do I reset the tracker?

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187191/tracker-process-taking-lot-of-cpu: `tracker reset --hard`

Comment: I also have just discovered ~/.cache/tracker/meta.db-wal taking 31GB of 263GB home partition (now 94% full) under Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, with meta.db taking 96MB. Total disk space (under LVM) is just under 2TB, according to df.

Comment: Got 107GB on that meta.db-wal