# Purging performance-reducing tracker-extract caused other issues

Tags: 20.04, purge, tracker

I run Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS I was having the problem that the tracker-extract was taking up a lot of CPU usage and was really slowing down the system. So I searched for a solution and found [this on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187191/tracker-process-taking-lot-of-cpu)

From which I executed this command:

`apt purge tracker tracker-extract tracker-miner-fs`

Now I have 2 issues

1. The Text Editor icon has disappeared from the dock (EDIT: after reading the below comment, I realized my mistake - its not the text editor icon that disappeared from the dock but the file manager icon)
2. The icons on the desktop have disappeared.

I tried a simple restart of Gnome for the second issue but this did not work.

I'm being honest when I say, I do not know what the above command does. I am happy to have the tracker-extract back if it is necessary to have the system run correctly.

I appreciate any advice.

Comment: You did not choose to follow the accepted answer in the thread you linked to. Did you start your file manager? I think it is gone too, although I was not expecting your text editor to go.

Comment: After reading your comment, I realized that it wasn't the text editor icon that disappeared from the dock but the file manager icon. I apologize for my mistake. Also, after reading your comment, I tried to start the file manager and realized it is not installed. So I installed it. I now have the desktop icon back in the dock. Thankyou

Comment: Use the "accepted" answer (and upvote if it works) to disable tracker. I answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

You followed the wrong approach to disable tracker. In Ubuntu 20.04 and up, the file manager `nautilus` depends on `tracker`. So removing `tracker` automatically uninstalls `nautilus` as well. And since the Gnome Shell desktop icons extension depends on `nautilus`, that is gone as well.

A fool-proof way to restore all your Ubuntu desktop components may be to reinstall the `ubuntu-desktop` package (which is gone too):

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`
```

This will restore your File manager, your desktop icons, and any other Ubuntu desktop compound you may have removed.

To disable Tracker, follow the [right approach](https://askubuntu.com/a/1187273/558158).