# I uninstalled tracker-extract and rebooted, after that file explorer disappeared. But files are not deleted. But I am unable to open the file explorer

Tags: 22.04

Today morning, I uninstalled tracker-extract, because it was eating more RAM, after that rebooted. Now I am not able to see files. I had added file explorer as fevorite, even that has gone. Please help me.

Comment: How did you uninstall ? What was the output  ?

Answer (score 2):

The file manager Files (nautilus) is dependent on Tracker, so removing Tracker will remove Files. Reinstall Files, then disable Tracker according to the instructions [elsewhere on this site](https://askubuntu.com/a/1187273/558158).