# High CPU used and battery drain First tracker and now Isolate+. What is happening?

Tags: power-management, battery, cpu, fan, overheating

I have an HP Elitebook. Few weeks ago I started to hear the fan working often. Using top I noticed that "tracker" was using almost all of the CPU. I fixed with a solution someone posted here: "sudo chmod -x /usr/libexec/tracker-extract-3". My OS was Ubuntu 20.04. Then I upgrade to 22.04, also de BIOS. Now I hear the fan working often again and as previously, draining the battery. With top I see now that Isolate+ is using almost all of the CPU. Could you please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance. Lautaro Vergara

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tracker process taking lot of CPU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187191/tracker-process-taking-lot-of-cpu)

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday night I think I solved the problem. It was snap.

See: https://itsfoss.com/pending-update-firefox-ubuntu/

L. vergara