why is tracker consuming 100% of my CPU, and I dont use PC
Why is tracker-miner-fs consuming 100% of my CPU. This is not the first time I see a similar situation, I already saw it in MySQL when I added jone query caching, and MySQL stopped working properly. Somehow, constantly porting free products, I just updated my Ubuntu, and got a computer that is impossible to use. My computer was slow for a month until I found the reason. I had to try hard to fix it.
Have you ever had this happen with product installations?

This question is similar to: Tracker process taking lot of CPU. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I solved the problem, I wonder why this happens.
It turns out that in order to perform a small function, to search in files, and tagging, which I almost never use, my computer slowed down for a month. It looks like Microsoft gave the developer a task, after which Ubuntu began to slow down...

I'm interested in the experience of other ubuntu users

Consider this solution. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179780/tracker-service-running-every-minute/1310748#1310748
