# tracker-miner-fs ubuntu 19.10

Tags: gnome, 19.10

I upgraded to Ubuntu 19.10 and, whenever I turn on the PC, a `tracker-miner-fs` error pops up and wants me to report it to Ubuntu.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Is it "normal"?

Comment: are you sure it is `tracker-min-fs` and not `tracker-miner-fs`? https://askubuntu.com/questions/346211/tracker-store-and-tracker-miner-fs-eating-up-my-cpu-on-every-startup

Comment: A screenshot may help!

Comment: Rinzwind yes its tracker-miner-fs. I'm so sorry
Problem Screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/tEGP61o

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue after upgrading to 19.10.

`tracker-miner-fs` is part of GNOME and indexes your files. See the description [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker).

A quick fix that is linked/mentioned in [the upstream issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/tracker-miners/issues/86) is to reset the tracker by deleting the folders `~/.cache/tracker` and `~/.local/share/tracker`.

After that the program starts without any issue.