# Sorry, Ubuntu 19.10 has experienced an internal error after upgrade

Tags: gnome, upgrade, mysql

Today I received a prompt informing me that I can upgrade to Ubuntu 19.10 (I'm currently running 19.04).

I started the upgrade however I had some issues with MySQL, which in turn broke the upgrade. I waited and the upgraded attempted to recover the itself by restarting the `mysql-server` related section, however, the same error came back. The upgrade finally completed but said there were some issues.

I restarted my laptop, everything seemed okay. I ran `neofetch` and got the following output which showed the new `19.10` version:

[image: neofetch output]

I then got a popup regarding the `mysql-server` install failure:

[image: mysql-server crash]

After a few seconds I was greeted with another popup regarding `tracker-miner-fs`:

[image: tracker-miner-fs crash]

Since writing this, attempting to grab the screenshots above, the screenshot app failed to open and then the app launcher failed to search for anything, so, I waited and then got the following crash error too regarding the `gnome-control-center`:

[image: gnome-control-center crash]

I managed to fix the GUI by running the following command in my terminal (which thankfully was already open from running `neofetch`)

`gnome-shell --replace & disown`

I appreciate that I may need to paste logs for anyone to assist with this, however, if you could specify information you'd need in a comment I will update the question accordingly. I don't want to paste lots of unnecessary log info if it isn't beneficial to the question.

I hope someone can help me fix these issues. I'm not a complete newbie when it comes to linux however I'm only familiar with basic commands and my knowledge of the ins and outs of Ubuntu is fairly minimal.

**EDIT (UPDATED)**

- `apt.log`: https://privatebin.net/?a9d9eae39130c6c0#6uWuPqYHf4CPEUbd4yqVGt8aG6NTxCHaTsCVSwX43mZo
- `apt-term.log`: https://privatebin.net/?6942e15393cc140f#HUshgyaYqMUPmddDB27SMFeSb1fL7FibWiVoTA54JhEB
- `history.log`: https://privatebin.net/?cd1c5f34962811fa#2kYU5AuMTD8G16wtkL3rPMmVuQMY6mVvFB4cc18X8c1s
- `main.log`: https://privatebin.net/?e9e1da94e9d12295#7tEcbicXb5QJiQ5EABnZkszHGhbYXpQ7cfwvqUY1ec9z

**EDIT 2**
Output of `sudo apt install --fix-missing`

```bsh
sudo apt install --fix-missing
[sudo] password for matt: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  example-content g++-8 geoclue geoclue-ubuntu-geoip gir1.2-mutter-4 libc++abi1-8 libcrystalhd3 libdouble-conversion1 libgeoclue0 libglade2-0 libigdgmm5 libllvm8
  libllvm8:i386 liblvm2app2.2 liblvm2cmd2.02 libmutter-4-0 libmysqlclient20 libnm-glib4 libnm-gtk0 libnm-util2 libpoppler85 libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer
  libstdc++-8-dev libtagc0 libwireshark11 libwiretap8 libwsutil9 libx265-165 linux-headers-5.0.0-36 linux-headers-5.0.0-36-generic linux-image-5.0.0-36-generic
  linux-modules-5.0.0-36-generic linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-36-generic mysql-client python-appindicator python-attr python-automat python-cairo python-certifi python-chardet
  python-click python-colorama python-constantly python-glade2 python-gobject python-gobject-2 python-gtk2 python-hyperlink python-idna python-incremental python-libtorrent
  python-notify python-numpy python-openssl python-pyasn1 python-pyasn1-modules python-pygame python-requests python-service-identity python-twisted-bin python-twisted-core
  python-urllib3 python-zope.interface
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 4 not to upgrade.
```

After running `sudo apt autoremove` and then `sudo apt install --fix-missing`:

```bsh
sudo apt install --fix-missing
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 6 not to upgrade.
```

Comment: We need to see all the errors you encountered during your release-upgrade. The description you have provided is much too vague to offer useful advice, sorry. Find the log at /var/log/dist-upgrade. Paste the entire log into a [pastebin](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Pastebin), and add a link to that log in your question above.

Comment: @user535733 no worries, I thought as much. As `/var/log/dist-upgrade` is a directory. Which log files will be useful? I have a directory dated today, which I assume contains the correct logs. Inside of there, I have the following: `apt.log`, `apt-term.log`, `history.log`, `main.log` and `xorg-fixup.log`. Which of these do you need if not all?

Comment: @user535733 have added links to all the above listed logs, pastebin was timing out so used privatebin

Comment: @user535733 oops that's awkward. I have updated the links with logs that are dated today :)

Comment: Looks like you added wrong-version packages or some non-Ubuntu source. Those cause such breakage; best practice is to revert back to Ubuntu-only sources and packages before a release-upgrade. You also seem to have mixed MySQL and MariaDB packages at some point. Please run `sudo apt install --fix-missing` and post the complete output above.

Comment: @user535733 have added the output of running that command to the end of my question

Comment: @user535733 I appreciate your help, if it's worth mentioning. I restarted my laptop and when I login I get the popup regarding `tracker-miner-fs` each time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more googling I stumbled across this Ask Ubuntu question: [tracker-miner-fs ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183223/tracker-miner-fs-ubuntu-19-10)

Following the answer posted there, which was to remove these two directories:

- `~/.cache/tracker`
- `~/.local/share/tracker`

I ran the following two commands:

`rm -rf ~/.cache/tracker` and `rm -rf ~/.local/share/tracker`

Since restarting my laptop the error popup has not re-appeared.