# Mouse lag after updating ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10

Tags: 19.10

I just updated my ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10. Update was successful but the mouse now lags even when 2gb out of 4 are used for the ram and CPU use is also low. This never happened with the older version. Is there anything I can do other than downgrade or restore ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:
by using `htop` instead of `cpu monitor`, I figured out that 100% of cpu was used in lower priority by `tracker-miner-fs`. I used the following script:

```
echo -e "\nHidden=true\n" | sudo tee --append /etc/xdg/autostart/tracker-extract.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/tracker-miner-apps.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/tracker-miner-fs.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/tracker-miner-user-guides.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/tracker-store.desktop > /dev/null
gsettings set org.freedesktop.Tracker.Miner.Files crawling-interval -2  
gsettings set org.freedesktop.Tracker.Miner.Files enable-monitors false  
tracker reset --hard
```

Taken from [Radu Rădeanu's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/348692/829702) to [tracker-store and tracker-miner-fs eating up my CPU on every startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346211/tracker-store-and-tracker-miner-fs-eating-up-my-cpu-on-every-startup).

Now everything works like a charm.