# Tracker miner uses almost all my CPU and fills syslog with errors

Tags: cpu, tracker

I've been working with huge data last week and at some point while procesing this data, tracker-miner started using almost all my CPU and now is filling my syslog with the same "error". I've read other solutions that were on this place but nothing seems to work with my computer. I have this on my syslog on loop:

```
Apr 27 21:07:55 vant-N2x0WU tracker-miner-f[2248]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
Apr 27 21:07:55 vant-N2x0WU tracker-miner-f[2248]: g_file_has_prefix: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
```

Every second the computer saves these two lines almost 10.000 times, the syslog archive is huge (+180GB) and I don't know if it's okay but the system has warned me that there is almost no space left. I have deleted the content with > /var/log/syslog but it still grows a lot again. Does anyone know what I can do or what could be the cause?

Btw, I have Ubuntu 21.10 and I've tied with `tracker reset --hard`,also with disabling it and deleting the large files if it's that what causes the errors but I'm afraid to do something that I can't fix later

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/346211/tracker-store-and-tracker-miner-fs-eating-up-my-cpu-on-every-startup

Comment: You have not said what version of Ubuntu you are using so I suggest you update your question with that information. Also you say you have read other solutions but without any information about what you have tried etc.